# using var main in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i try to load View with javascript in Codeigniter :

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        var id = 0;
        var main = "view-to-load.php";

        $("#data-show").load(main);
```

and looks like it failed. Could you show me the right syntax?

googling with keyword "javascript var main to load view in codeigniter" show me nothing or would you show me the link for equal topic in this forum.

thank you verymuch

Comment: Did you try to store the view in the php variable and load using javascript?

Comment: You cannot directly load a view. At least views should be outside your public folder (document root). Intead load them through a controller with a standard request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View files are used internally by your CodeIgniter Controller functions to construct the final output... you are never supposed to be accessing these directly from the browser either by URL or Ajax.  [If you've followed guidelines for "best security"](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html), your `application` directory will not be stored in the `www` or `public_html` directory, so therefore you cannot directly or publicly load any file from within `application` into the browser.

Construct a [CodeIgniter Controller](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) function that shows the desired [View (content)](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) at a particular URL.  *Then* you can use Ajax to load this URL.

**Example Controller:**

```
<?php
class Demo extends CI_Controller {

    function mypage()
    {
        $this->load->view('view-to-load.php');
    }

}
```

**Publicly access your content at this URL:**

```
example.com/demo/mypage/
```

---

You should also review [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

It appears that you've wrapped a DOM ready handler inside of a DOM ready handler.  Normally, it does not break anything, but it's pointless.

Comment: my mistake, looks like it works now :) i need to read more about the theory. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer console of Firefox and go to the "network" tab, then reload your page. Now you should see the AJAX query deployed by the `load` command and it will probably have a wrong absolute url and will thus not succeed.

I suppose the solution is to give either an absolute url of your view file or a correct relative one, e.g. `application/views/view-to-load.php`.

Comment: i try this to, var main = "../../application/views/view-to-load.php"; but still won't work. i develop on xampp. thanks

Comment: If you look at the "network" tab as explained above you should see what URL the browser tries to get - that should clarify what URL you need to specify.

Comment: The CodeIgniter application directory is not supposed to be inside the `www` or `public_html` directory.  Therefore, you cannot access any of the view files directly from the browser.  In other words, if you cannot even see the URL from the browser, then JavaScript is not going to matter.